# Are same name in different directory the same thing?

Tags: files, directory, directory-structure

For example, on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2 there are

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server
/etc/logrotate.d/rabbitmq-server
/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server
```

more than 4 'kinds' of `rabbitmq-server` (in fact there are 2 other ones ), are they the same thing? I mean, if I want to start `rabbitmq` can I use either of those command `rabbitmq-server`?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the unclear title! Everyone knows same name files in different directory may contain different things. I wanted to ask whether that also apply to programs, I hope I made that clear in my question. I apology for that, however, I'm not changing the tile for there are already two answers for the title (for my real questions as well, thanks!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are totally different and have different content.

For example I have

```
A/file
B/file

$ cat A/file
hello

$ cat B/file
there
```

We can see they say different things.

In your case:

`/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server` - this will be the startup at boot time script

`/etc/logrotate.d/rabbitmq-server` - this will manage the log files

`/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server` - this is the main server program that's started by the `init` script

`/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server` - this is part of your HA configuration.

So all 4 files do different things.

Comment: Note that they may not all be different, some may be symlinks to others. I wouldn't be surprised if `etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server` linked to `/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server`. You could always use `readlink` to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Much like in many environments, it's certainly possible to have multiple files with the same name in several locations.

There are several ways to see if the files are identical (or indeed are the same file with multiple links).

First, you can use a tool such as `diff` to compare the contents of files.  If they are different, you will be shown the differences (or informed that they are different if the files are interpreted to be binary files):

```
diff /etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server /etc/logrotate.d/rabbitmq-server
```

Secondly, you can use the long form of `ls` to see if a file is a symbolic (or "soft" link.  This will show both that a given file is a symbolic link, and the location to which it points:

```
$ ls -l bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ghoti ghoti 3 Aug 18 18:34 bar -> foo
```

The `l` in the first column shows that `bar` is a link, and the end of the line, `bar -> foo`, shows that `foo` is the location to which `bar` points.

`ls -l` will also show you how many hard links a file has:

```
$ ls -l foo
-rw-rw-r-- 2 ghoti ghoti 0 Aug 18 18:36 foo
```

In this case, the `2` between the permissions and the owner shows that `foo` is a file to which there are two hard links.  You can use `find` to locate files that are hardlinks to the same file:

```
find / -samefile foo
```

The above command will search the entire filesystem for all hardlinks to `foo`

As to your question about the correct way to start `rabbitmq`, this is best found by consulting the manual page:

```
man rabbitmq
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I'm sorry for the unclear title, I was not intended to ask the question you answered, my bad. Thanks for your precious time, I really appreciate it.